# correction in java program

Tags: java, user-interface

```
import  javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
class TestGui //implements ActionListener,WindowsListener
{
    JFrame f;
    JButton b[]=new JButton[11];
    JTextField Jt;
    TestGui()
    {
        f=new JFrame("Praneet");
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            b[i]=new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            b[i].setBounds(i*50+50,i*50+50,50,50);
            f.add(b[i]);
        }
        f.setSize(900,900);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        new TestGui();
    }
}
```

What is wrong in the code button 9 is occupying whole frame.
I need to have buttons I diagonal manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFrame uses **BorderLayout** as default layout. You need to set layout value to `null` to see your last button at the end instead of covering the whole layout.

Use this after initializing the JFrame to remove the layout:

```
f.setLayout(null);
```